# Why is flux for constant vector fields defined with the dot product instead of the cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, surfaces, volume, fluid-dynamics

If you look at a diagram, the flux seems to be a parallelogram that represents the volume of water (for example) that passes through the surface. See this diagram in my text: [image: o]

But I thought the volumes of parallelograms were calculated using the cross product, not the dot product? That diagram is exactly the kind of situation I'd imagine using the cross product in...

Comment: The volume of a parallelepiped is computed using a triple product, not a cross product. A triple product is essentially some sort of determinant among three vectors. It can be evaluated as a cross product (for the base) followed by a dot product (for the direction perpendicular to the base). In the formula flux = $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A}$, the cross product is absorbed in the definition of $\vec{A}$.

Comment: @achillehui Ahh okay I was getting myself confused with the differences then. That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area vector of a flat surface has apparently in your text been defined to be perpendicular to the surface.  If we want to measure flow *through* a surface, we want to know the amount of velocity vector is parallel to the area vector (i.e., perpendicular to the surface).

The diagram is perhaps a little confusing.  The area $A$ is a parallelogram drawn on the floor.  Its area vector points up, perpendicular to the floor.  The velocity vector points somewhere in the halfspace above the floor.  The empty parallelogram is parallel transported along $v$ in one unit of time (whatever time units you are using).  The volume of flow extruded through the parallelogram on the floor is the area of that parallelogram times the height (measured perpendicularly to the floor) of the [parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) standing on it (bounded by the two parallelograms and the four dotted lines).

If $v$ is parallel to the area vector, then the height is as large as it can be and also, the flow through the parallelogram is maximized.  If $v$ is parallel to the floor, there is no flow through the parallelogram (all flow is along the parallelogram), so the volume of the parallelepiped is zero.  The dot product is maximized when parallel and zero when perpendicular, which reproduces the desired behaviour.  The cross product is zero when parallel and maximized when perpendicular, which is exactly the opposite of the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This is a great way of thinking about it that is able to get past all the mental blocks I had, I'll definitely be keeping your description in mind as I move on with this stuff. Thank you!